# Get the oldest email in inbox using GMail API (First In- First Out)

Tags: gmail-api

I want to get the oldest email in GMail inbox. What is the best way to do this action?
Using the API I cannot find any option that allows me to get the most oldest using the way FIFO: First In- First Out

Thanks you,

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do this, you would need to first list messages (you can use a query like `older_than:5y`) get the ids, then make requests for each id to get the date information. Maybe if you give some more context about what you are trying to accomplish I could suggest more.

Comment: Hi @iansedano! Thank you for respond. I am working on a queue of cases from Gmail. I must always take the older case. No matter how many cases I have in my inbox. About your Idean, Im think to use your idea about older_than:Ny .. and use the N as counter. I can loop the counter in order to take the older case per day. But I don't know if it the best way.

Comment: You can also do something similar with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). You could for example try and set up a label for all the queue cases. Then a simple gmail filter to add the labels as they come in. Then you could have a script on a (time driven trigger)[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers] to process the emails as they come in and add them to a queue in a spreadsheet, and add a "processed" label to them. There are many ways, all with good and bad points. Try one, maybe don't think about whether its the "best"